# Species Identification: Small white maggot/larvae, Missouri USA

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I'll try to give as much information as I can, because I don't know which information will be more important.

We woke up this morning to these little white worm/larvae in the house. We are located in the northern portion of southeast Missouri. We live next to some horses and cows. We have 1 inside dog and 1 outside dog. I'd say more of the worms were found in the kitchen (Tile floor) but some were also found in the living room (Hardwood floor).

This is a side view of the worm.[image: Worm Side View]

This is a perspective view of the worm. (About a 1/2 inch long)[image: Worm with Measurment]

Comment: It's the larvae of an insect - probably a house fly/bluebottle (it looks very similar to the typed used for/bought from fishing suppliers as "maggots")

Comment: Try to keep it in a jar and see if becomes an adult, that will be easier to ID.

Comment: We've kept one to the side. We'll see what happens. We've also called a pest control in our area to come and look to see what they think about the situation.

Comment: What ever became of the specimen you kept? Any adult pictures?

Comment: I kept some in a jar, but they all turned hard and brown. I assumed they died. I left them for a while just in case, but they never did anything. I'm kinda hoping they come back. I want to try again!